# How to set up a raster legend for four plots in a panel?

Tags: r, raster, legend-properties

I done four raster plots which were 2 layered and I done pretty simple using par(mfrow=c(2,2)), but when setting a common legend makes the plot a mess, It always overlap with other plots. I tried change some parameter values but still the issue persists. this is my code.

```
    library(maps)
library(raster)

# set colour
col<- colorRampPalette(c("grey","green","green3","darkgreen"))
#set panel for four plots    
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(2,2,2,2),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
#plot1
plot(novchl,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(novsst,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot2
plot(decchl,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(decsst,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot3
plot(janchl,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(jansst,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot4
plot(febchl,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(febsst,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
reset para to single plot
par(mfrow=c(1,1),new=FALSE,mar=c(0,0,0,8))
plot(novchl,legend.only=TRUE ,legend.shrink=1, legend.width=1, zlim=c(0, 1),
     axis.args=list(at=pretty(0:1), labels=pretty(0:1)),col=col(20),
     legend.args=list(text='Whatever',"bottom", font=2, line=2.3))
```

and I got image like this.plz help, thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adressing the *overlapping*-topic of your question without considering any other changes in the layout (and not adressing the warning messages). To get a MWE, I use the `test-grid` data from the **raster** package.

I think you were almost there (mark the `oma` arguments in the calls to `par`)...

Set the *4th* entry in your `oma` argument in your first call to `par` to something higher than `0` in order to leave some space on the *right* side. Then, when resetting the parameters to a single plot, also reset this value to e.g. `0` to place the legend on the empty space. Something like this

```
library(maps)
library(raster)

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))

# set colour
col<- colorRampPalette(c("grey","green","green3","darkgreen"))
#set panel for four plots    
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(2,2,2,2),oma=c(0,0,0,4))
#plot1
plot(r,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(r,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot2
plot(r,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(r,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot3
plot(r,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(r,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")
#plot4
plot(r,col=col(20),legend =FALSE)
contour(r,maxpixels = 999,add=TRUE)
map(xlim=c(85, 93),ylim=c(2, 16 ),asp=1,add=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col="grey")

#reset para to single plot
par(mfrow=c(1,1),new=FALSE, oma=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(r,legend.only=TRUE ,legend.shrink=1, legend.width=1, zlim=c(0, 1),
     axis.args=list(at=pretty(0:1), labels=pretty(0:1)),col=col(20),
     legend.args=list(text='Whatever',"bottom", font=2, line=2.3))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked well, I think this means we need to give space from previous plots.

Comment: yes, that's it. If that helped, it would be nice if you could accept this response as the answer.